# How can I position an image like this?

Tags: html

How can I position a href image in to the same line as the other one? I tried padding-bottom but it won't do it.(the border is so that I can see where it should go in). For some reason i can't find how to place one of them next to the other one. I have this html:

```html
<h1 style="padding-left:25px">Wholesome Clips</h1>
  <div class = "imagesBox" style="padding-left:40px;">
  <a href="https://www.twitch.tv/legion_exordiri/clip/CautiousTameTruffleHassanChop?filter=clips&range=all&sort=time" target="_blank" >
     <img style="border:groove;" src="https://clips-media-assets2.twitch.tv/AT-cm%7C923609230-preview-260x147.jpg" title="Click here!" alt="The thumbnail for this clip couldn't be loaded." width="500" height="300"></img>
     <h3>Chat said you're very cool...</h3>
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.twitch.tv/legion_exordiri/clip/RelievedMotionlessLasagnaAMPEnergy?filter=clips&range=all&sort=time" target="_blank">
    <img style="border:groove;" src="https://clips-media-assets2.twitch.tv/AT-cm%7C911141051-preview-260x147.jpg" title="Click here!" alt="The thumbnail for this clip couldn't be loaded." width="500" height="300"></img>
     <h3>Adorable High Five</h3>
  </a>
    <p id="counterPoggers"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: you want both images to be side by side ?

Comment: yes, basically that's what I'm going for.

Comment: If one of the answers is correct please tick answered so that we can close this post. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) with `flex-direction: row`:

```css
.imagesBox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<h1 style="padding-left:25px">Wholesome Clips</h1>
<div class="imagesBox" style="padding-left:40px;">
<div>
  <a href="https://www.twitch.tv/legion_exordiri/clip/CautiousTameTruffleHassanChop?filter=clips&range=all&sort=time" target="_blank">
    <img style="border:groove;" src="https://clips-media-assets2.twitch.tv/AT-cm%7C923609230-preview-260x147.jpg" title="Click here!" alt="The thumbnail for this clip couldn't be loaded." width="500" height="300"></img>
    <h3>Chat said you're very cool...</h3>
  </a>
  </div>
  <a href="https://www.twitch.tv/legion_exordiri/clip/RelievedMotionlessLasagnaAMPEnergy?filter=clips&range=all&sort=time" target="_blank">
    <img style="border:groove;" src="https://clips-media-assets2.twitch.tv/AT-cm%7C911141051-preview-260x147.jpg" title="Click here!" alt="The thumbnail for this clip couldn't be loaded." width="500" height="300"></img>
    <h3>Adorable High Five</h3>
  </a>
  <p id="counterPoggers"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: This works but the images became very small, how can I adjust their size?

Comment: @MusicAllen I changed the `width` and `height` of the images just so they will fit the snippet here. You should keep them the same as they were, ill add a note about in my answer

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't notice that. I thought it just became automatically this size.

Comment: @MusicAllen no, my bad :) I fixed my answer

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved in many ways. You can use flexbox.

Add the `display: flex` in your div

```
<div class = "imagesBox" style="display: flex">
  //...
</div>
```

```html
<h1 style="padding-left:25px">Wholesome Clips</h1>
  <div class = "imagesBox" style="display: flex">
  <a href="https://www.twitch.tv/legion_exordiri/clip/CautiousTameTruffleHassanChop?filter=clips&range=all&sort=time" target="_blank" >
     <img style="border:groove;" src="https://clips-media-assets2.twitch.tv/AT-cm%7C923609230-preview-260x147.jpg" title="Click here!" alt="The thumbnail for this clip couldn't be loaded." width="500" height="300"></img>
     <h3>Chat said you're very cool...</h3>
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.twitch.tv/legion_exordiri/clip/RelievedMotionlessLasagnaAMPEnergy?filter=clips&range=all&sort=time" target="_blank">
    <img style="border:groove;" src="https://clips-media-assets2.twitch.tv/AT-cm%7C911141051-preview-260x147.jpg" title="Click here!" alt="The thumbnail for this clip couldn't be loaded." width="500" height="300"></img>
     <h3>Adorable High Five</h3>
  </a>
    <p id="counterPoggers"></p>
</div>
```